# Best practices regarding warning outputs when compiling in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I'm learning c and am compiling all my programs using gcc in linux subsystem for windows.

I learned that I can include some flags by the gcc standards. Some include the basic -o or -lm.
I discovered the -Wall flag and it has outputted some warnings in my shell that I fix.

Right now my usual gcc compilation line usually lies along the lines of `cc -Wall -lm -o file.exe file.c`.

I recently learned that there are a lot of other flags that can be included, some regarding warnings; one is `-w`, which is supposed to show even more warnings than `-Wall`, so my question is -

1- Should I always specify `-w`? or is there any drawbacks or maybe even incorrect issued warnings?

2- Also, what are the best practices when compiling a program, i.e., what options/flags do you always turn on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The more professional you become the more warnings you strive to enable. My current favorite set is `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` which gives a good average.

   If you think you receive a false warning, think again. Almost always the compiler is right. Until you become an intimate expert with the C standard you better ask, for example here on SO.

   Some think that `-Werror` has some value, and for their development process they are probably right. Since I use some kind of build control software (namely "make") I don't need it, because GCC returns non-zero values on warnings, too.
2. All other flags depend on the purpose of the command. Some examples:

   - `-o` is great to define the name of the output file.
   - *(EDIT)*`-O…` sets the optimization level; some years ago `-O3` might have some problems but today it should be fine.
   - `-s` strips the debug information from the output; good for the release version.
   - `-g` includes debug information to the output; there are variants depending on your goal.
   - `-Wl,--wrap…` is really sophisticated for special debugging and/or testing; read its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Another best practise can be considered the often use of `-Wfatal-errors`

GCC compiler errors can sometimes be several pages long (especially so if you ever have to compile C++ code).  There are several reasons for while compiler errors can be so long; a typical example is some missing brackets at the top of the file, which causes the compiler to report errors for many lines of the remainder of the file.

Seasoned developers know to initially direct their attention on the top-most error, and fixing that often solves all the following pages of errors.  To help with this working practise, you can add the `-Wfatal-errors` to tell gcc that you only want to see the *first* error, and that it should stop trying to compile the rest of the code once a compilation error is detected.  Thus you never get the daunting pages of output that you have to scroll through.

Best practice is then switching to and from this `-Wfatal-errors` mode, or just leave it mostly on, only occasionally turning it off when you would like to see more errors for a particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I always specify -w?

`-w` removes all warning messages. You should not use `-w`.

If you meant `-W`, it's an old flag for `-Wextra`, has the same meaning as `-Wextra`.

Also, rules are not absolute. Not *always*, there are project specific needs and recommendations. If I write a short program, I sometimes use like `gcc -ansi -xc - <<<'a;b;main() { printf("%d\n", a * b); }` because I'm in a hurry. But *usually*, if not always, you should enable as many warnings as you can.

> or is there any drawbacks or maybe even incorrect issued warnings?

The drawbacks of too many warnings are coming from too many enabled warnings - clutter in compiler output, while irrelevant warnings hide important stuff. The warnings I do not like:

- unused functions `-Wunused-function`
- unused function parameters `-Wunused-parameter`

Although code may be perfectly fine, ton of "unused function" warnings may be issued, while these functions may be used in like different project configuration chosen by different macro definitions.

> what are the best practices when compiling a program, i.e., what options/flags do you always turn on?

I recommend for warnings: `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter`

I also recommend following flags to write safe code and protect against runtime mistakes: `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=leak -fsanitize=pointer-subtract -fsanitize=pointer-compare -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fstack-protector-all -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection`

Fun fact: `-Wwrite-strings` is not enabled with `-Wall -Wextra` and looks like a valuable warning to me.

See also [redhat recommended compiler and linker flags for GCC](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/03/21/compiler-and-linker-flags-gcc/).

With gcc10 [static analyzer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html) options are also worth a look.